# noUiSlider convert pips to logarithmic appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nouislider

I have several [noUiSliders](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) like the example below. I would like to change the numeric pip and slider value to a logarithmic appearance. So with the example below I would like the middle value to be 10 million (and not 50 million). So the steps between e.g. 100.000 to 250.000 are smaller than between 23 million and 30 million. Something like this:

|----|----|----|----|----|--------|--------|-------------------|-------------|
0                        7Mio  10Mio   25Mio                         100Mio

I checked the noUiSlider-Website and other websites too, but I did not get an approach on how to start this. So I am asking you for help on this. Thank you in advance for reading my issue.

```js
//format the pips
function filterPips(value, type) {
  if (type === 0) {
    return value < 2000 ? -1 : 0;
  }
return value % 1000 ? 2 : 1;
}

var rangeSliderGehalt = document.getElementById('slider-range-gehalt');

noUiSlider.create(rangeSliderGehalt, {
    start: [100000],
    connect: [true, false],
    step: 100000,
    behaviour: 'tap-drag',
    tooltips: true,
    range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100000000]
    },
    pips: {
        mode: 'positions',
        values: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        density: 4,
        stepped: true,
        filter: filterPips,
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: '.',
            postfix: ' €'
        })
    },
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0, // default is 2
        thousand: '.', // thousand delimiter
        postfix: ' €', // gets appended after the number
    })
});
var rangeSliderGehaltValueElement = document.getElementById('result-gehalt');

rangeSliderGehalt.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    rangeSliderGehaltValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle];
});

var valueInput = document.getElementById('value-input'),
    valueSpan = document.getElementById('value-span');

// When the slider value changes, update the input and span
rangeSliderGehalt.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    if (handle) {
        valueInput.value = values[handle];
    } else {
        //valueSpan.innerHTML = values[handle];
    }
});

// When the input changes, set the slider value
if (valueInput) {
    valueInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
        rangeSliderGehalt.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
    });
}
```

```css
.label{
  margin-top:50px;
}

.slider{
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.1.0/nouislider.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.1.0/wNumb.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider">
  <div id="slider-range-gehalt"></div>
</div>

<div class="label">
  <label for="gf">Slider value: </label>
  <span id="result-gehalt"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I am just not able to check the documentation of noUiSliders.  I was so fixed on that specific "logarithmic stuff" that I forgot to check for "non linear". However, the solution is, to just tell the range what value and what step you would like to have at what percentage of the slider.

Solutionlink: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/

So I just changed the code:

```
range: {
        'min': [0, 50000], //stepsize is 50.000
        '5%': [500000, 100000], //stepsize is 100.000
        '25%': [7000000],
        '50%': [10000000],
        '75%': [60000000, 500000], //stepsize is 500.000
        'max': [100000000]
    },
```

Thanks a lot for those, who came across.